# Python: Static variable (or, difference between class.some_var and inst.some_var)

Tags: python, oop, static

I have simple class written

```
class Test:

    stat = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.inst = 10

    def printa(self):
        print Test.stat
        print self.inst
```

Now I've created two object of this class

```
$ a = Test()
$ b = Test()
```

When I say `a.printa()` or `b.printa()` it outputs `0 10` which is understandable.

But when I say

```
$ a.stat = 2
$ print a.stat
```

It'll output

```
2
```

But when I say `a.printa()`
It'll output

```
1
10
```

What's the difference between saying `objInstance.staticVar` and `ClassName.staticVar`?? What it is doing internally?

Comment: While the same mechanism is being discussed, this is not a duplicate of [Static class variables in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you do something to change how attribute assignment works (with `__setattr__` or descriptors), assigning to `some_object.some_attribute` always assigns to an instance attribute, **even if there was already a class attribute with that name**.

Thus, when you do

```
a = Test()
```

`a.stat` is the class attribute. But after you do

```
a.stat = 2
```

`a.stat` now refers to the instance attribute. The class attribute is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

By

```
1
10
```

I assume you mean

```
0
10
```

since the class variable `stat` was never changed.

To answer your question, it does this because you added an instance member variable `stat` to the `a` object. Your `objInstance.staticVar` isn't a static variable at all, it's that new variable you added.

Comment: Anyone want to explain the downvote so I can fix the problem?